# Responsive Email issues

Tags: css, email, media-queries, newsletter

After few days of struggling coding a responsive Email and trying to find answers all over the web, my Media Queries are not used by mobile devices, I compared it to ready-made responsive template, tested, tested and tested again with different configurations... But still it's not working here is my header :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <style type="text/css">

        table[class=w600], td[class=w600] {width: 600px!important;}
        body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 599px), only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {

            table[class=w600], td[class=w600] {width: 480px!important;}
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
            table[class=w600], td[class=w600] {width: 320px!important;}
            p[class=for-pro], a[class=view-in] {font-size: 10px!important;}
            p[class=bottom] {font-size: 12px!important;}
            p[class=frank] {font-size: 16px!important;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Am I missing something? What's the 'magic' stuff I need to write to make it works, because it's actually a very simple newsletter and as you can see, with only few css rules to follow.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't ... just don't push it ... email clients aren't following any standards ... You cannot create a responsive email that works well everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things: 1. What browser/client are you testing in?  IOS will respond responsively; however, Android's native app does not (Android 4.4).
2.  Do not use h1, h2, . . . p tags.  They respond differently depending on the email client.  Apply all styles to the containing `<td>`.

Here is my default head that I start most single column emails with.  It takes care of a lot of hacks you might encounter with yahoo, ios, and outlook.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>One Column Mobile Friendly Template</title>

<style>
/*------------------------------------*\
   EMAIL CLIENT SPECIFIC STYLES
\*------------------------------------*/
.ReadMsgBody, .ExternalClass { width:100%; } /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width */  
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height:100%; } /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display normal line spacing */
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote { -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; } /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile from changing default text sizes */
table, td { mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; } /* Removes spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; } /* Allows smoother rendering of resized images in Internet Explorer */
.footer a { color:/*#ffffff*/; text-decoration:none; } /* Add this class to the system footer to change the unsubscribe link ---does not work for Gmail--- */
.iOSfix a { color:/*#ffffff*/; text-decoration:none; } /* Override the default blue link style that iOS puts on address and phone numbers */
.iOSfixaside a { color:/*#000000*/; text-decoration:none; } /* Alternate Style - Override the default blue link style that iOS puts on address and phone numbers */
.em-dragdrop-dummy { display:none!important; }

/*------------------------------------*\
   RESET STYLES
\*------------------------------------*/
body { min-width:100% !important; }
html { width:100%; }
img { border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none; }
table { border-collapse:collapse !important; }
body, .emWrapperTable, .emWrapperCell { height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; }  
.mobileHeaderWidth .em-dockitem-empty, .mobileFooterWidth .em-dockitem-empty, .emWrapperTable, .emWrapperCell { width:100% !important; }
div { padding:0px !important; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { display:block; margin:0px; }

/*------------------------------------*\
   MOBILE STYLES
\*------------------------------------*/    
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px)  {
    td[class="mobileHeaderCell"],
    td[class="mobileColumnCell"],
    td[class="mobileFooterCell"] { display:block !important; }
    table[class="mobileHeaderWidth"],
    table[class="mobileColumnWidth"],
    table[class="mobileFooterWidth"],
    td[class="mobileHeaderCell"],
    td[class="mobileColumnCell"],
    td[class="mobileFooterCell"] {width:480px!important;}

    /* general display styles */
    td {box-sizing:border-box; }
    span[class="mHide"] { display:none!important; }
    span[class="mBreak"] { display:block!important; }
    p[class="mCenter"] { text-align:center!important; margin:0px 1em!important; }

    /* link styles */

    /* image styles */
    img[class="mFullImage"] { width:100%!important; height:auto!important; }
    img[class="mImgCenter"] { margin:0px auto!important; }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 479px) {
    table[class="mobileHeaderWidth"],
    table[class="mobileColumnWidth"],
    table[class="mobileFooterWidth"],
    td[class="mobileHeaderCell"],
    td[class="mobileColumnCell"],
    td[class="mobileFooterCell"] { width:320px!important; }

    /* general display styles */

    /* link styles */

    /* image styles */
}       
</style>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all mobile devices or mobile apps support responsive and media queries.
For example Android or Gmail app won't. There are some workaround. Especially to get it working on Android and to force it to render Desktop on Gmail. You can find the solution for Android here: 
[How to get a responsive HTML email to work on Android?](https://atcodegirl.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/how-to-get-a-responsive-html-email-to-work-on-android/)

Keeping that in mind, about the media queries you can try and set them up this way:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css"> 
     @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
       *[class].classname{width:100% !important;}
       *[class].classname{float:left !important;}
       *[class].classname{display:block !important;}
     }
     </style>
    </head>
```

Its fully explained here:
[How to code a responsive HTML email table step by step – tutorial](https://atcodegirl.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/how-to-code-a-responsive-html-email-table-step-by-step-tutorial/)